# subscribe to multiple writables at once

Tags: svelte

I have a counter

```
function createCountable(initValue: number, delta:number = 1) {
    const count = writable(initValue);

    return {
        value: count,
        inc: () => count.update(n => n + delta),
        dec: () => count.update(n => n - delta),
    };
}
```

and a store

```
function createStore() {
    const cycles = createCountable(4, 1)
    const cycleLength = createCountable(30, 5)

    let time: string = '00:00'

    //todo how to subscribe??

    return {
        cycles,
        cycleLength,
        time
    }
}
```

Whenever `cycles` or `cycleLength` updates, I want to recalculate the time. How can I handle this in one function / one subscription?

Or should I instead redesign the architecture of my store?

The reason I have two writables is because I like to encapsulate the value with its modifying functions for maintenance reasons also I can have polymorphism in my update function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at derived stores. I would write your example like this

```js
const cycles = createCountable(5, 1);
const cycleLength = createCountable(30, 5);

const time = derived([cycles, cycleLength], ([$cycles, $cycleLength]) => {
    return "00:00" // do whatever you like here
})
```

Then in your component, when you update cycles or cycleLengths, the $time will automatically update.

I haven't tested it, but I think it works

For more info, look at the [docs](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/derived-stores).